# Anyway to speed up renaming controls in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide, refactoring

I am working in visual studio 2010 on many projects, all projects are similar, and are modified from 1 project which was used as a template, but when I was trying to rename the controls to a new name for this specific project, it takes forever to  rename controls, and when it has over 100 controls it takes about 4 hours!

The problem has been posted [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628291-Slow-IDE-%28so-what-else-is-new%29-faster-way-of-naming-controls) but no solution seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying everything possible, this worked:

In Visual Studio, go to Tools>Options, Under Windows form designer > Refactoring, change EnableRefactoringOnRename to False.

This will speed up amazingly from 12 seconds to less than 1 second per control!

[image: VS 2010]

If you ever need this as a function to refactor automatically any reference to this control in your project, you can always go back and enable it.